# How does Multi-GPU scale in terms of memory allocation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a PC with the following specs:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990wx (32 cores)
- RAM: 32GB
- Graphics cards: (GPU:1) GTX1080 Ti (11GB), (GPU:0) GTX1070 (8GB)
- SSD: 2TB Samsung Evo 890

My question is, when I run my training program using Keras on roughly 60k images (GPU:1), the program loads the images and the data matrix is 12922.20MB

[image: screenshot of program]

After this, the program doesn't do anything for a minute and is killed automatically. The same code seems to be training on GPU:1 and working fine with 10k images.

1. Could this be because my GPU:1 can store only 11GB and the the data size is around 12GB?
2. Would parallelising GPU:1 and GPU:0 solve my problem? If so, would it be 16GB VRAM(8+8) or 19GB (11+8)?
3. Am I doing something wrong? The post I am referring is: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python with some minor modifications.

I did try to search online and on SO but I couldnt find/understand much information on how GPU memory is allocated/scales when using Multi-GPU with Keras.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Images are probably not loaded in the VRAM, but in your RAM. Did you check your PC RAM usage?

Answer (score 1):

I would first recommend that you check the memory usage when training on a single GPU; I suspect that your dataset is not loaded into the GPU memory but into the RAM.

You can try to set:

1.

```
  import os
  #Enable system to see only one of the video cards
  os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"/"1"
```

Check to see the exact mapping(that tensorflow sees your GPU):

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

2. Now verify exactly how much VRAM is used in this case:

Then, in the terminal you can use `nvidia-smi` to check how much GPU memory has been alloted; at the same time, using `watch -n K nvidia-smi`

3. When you use multi-gpus, ensure that you use `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()` and declare your model creation+fit logic like below:

   ```
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

    # Open a strategy scope.
    with strategy.scope():
      # Everything that creates variables should be under the strategy scope.
      # In general this is only model construction & `compile()`.
      model = Model(...)
      model.compile(...)
   ```

#### Outside the strategy scope

```
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, ...)

model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have it working and training just fine on one GPU, but with 10k samples (3x classes)

Comment: Also, wrt the VRAM being used, even if I train a small data set, it still uses all the RAM

Comment: Yes, that is good, at least it trains on the GPU. And it only fails when you try to use multiple GPUS? Did you use MirroredStrategy() for multi-gpu or Keras multi_gpu_model?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I haven't dabbled with multi-GPU yet. I wanted to be certain on how the allocation will work before I dive into this. Currently I was able to train a much larger dataset by increasing the SWAP memory by 64GB so I think this has solved my problem currently, but I would really like to get started with multi-GPU training and will play around with MirroredStrategy() and see how the machine behaves :D

Comment: Something is wrong there; you shouldn't need to increase the swap memory in order to be able to train. If this happens, then it means that the GPU is not used properly, although at allocation level Tensorflow is able to see it.

Comment: Oh... that’s concerning then, I’ll update the question with the code I’m running